# add a string in htaccess based on a string value

Tags: .htaccess

I want to change the url

FROM

http://www.example.com/option=com_content&view=propertyshow&pid=47610

TO

http://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=propertyshow&pid=47610

How can I do it in .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

This should do.

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [PT,L]
```